# Highlight Duplicate Within 24 hours timestamp but a different date

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to figure if the following can be done. If there are duplicate names in the B column then it will see if the date and time were within 24 hours of each other in the A column, if so it will highlight the cell yellow.

Currently, the formula I have will only highlight if it was on the same date. Is there a way I can add to the formula to all take into account time? So that if one response is on 5/20/20 at 17:00 and the next duplicate name is at 5/21/20 at 16:00 then the cell would be highlighted.

Here is the formula I am using the just highlights if it is within the same date:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, DATEVALUE(A:A), DATEVALUE(A2))>1)
```

I am not sure if something like this is possible. I am guessing that the formula would have to compare both datevalue and timevalue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Instead of `DATEVALUE` you can use `TO_PURE_NUMBER`

This will return you the number of days from January 1, 1900 including the fraction for past hours and minutes opposed to `DATEVALUE` that rounds the value down to an integral day number.

Sample:

[image]

This allows you to calculate the real difference time between your timestamp.

For example like this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(or(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, TO_PURE_NUMBER(A:A), ">"&TO_PURE_NUMBER(A2)-1, TO_PURE_NUMBER(A:A), "<"&TO_PURE_NUMBER(A2))>0,COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, TO_PURE_NUMBER(A:A), "<"&TO_PURE_NUMBER(A2)+1,TO_PURE_NUMBER(A:A), ">"&TO_PURE_NUMBER(A2))>0))`